# Вычислить остаток от деления

Tags: matlab

Посчитать mod(1000!, 333)
Главная проблема, что ответ должен выводиться вплоть до самого последнего символа в виде строки (т.е. НЕ в экспоненциальном виде, как обычно)

Comment: Дык ответ 0, что его там выводить?

Comment: В этом и загвоздка: {куча цифр}%{чуть меньше цифр} маловероятно что поделится нацело, т.е. результат != 0, а matlab стабильно выдаёт 0.
Я высчитал и вывел на экран 1000! вплоть до последней цифры (с помощью vpa), а вот нахождение остатка никак не получается

Comment: хорошая шутка) ответ 0 - правильный!

Comment: Самое обидное, что это не шутка и что я просто для примера 333 написал :-(, и ведь сколько геморроя было...
Ладно спасибо добры люди, хоть развлёк кого-то

Comment: Так а где шутка? В 1000! есть множитель 333, так что на это число результат делиться. Остаток - ноль. Как и на любое число до 1000. И (почти) любое составное с множителями до 1000

Comment: Неуч - каюсь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1000!       = 1 * 2 * 3 * ... 332 * 333 * 334 * ... * 999 * 1000
1000! / 333 = 1 * 2 * 3 * ... 332       * 334 * ... * 999 * 1000
```

То есть `1000!` делится на `333` нацело, ответ `0`.

Comment: Ааа, извини, пожалуйста, я опять забыл что при редактировании поста тебе прилетит минус(((